# Any better word for "upsell"

Tags: word-choice, business-language

My company provides more value to my clients by offering them services that could enhance their business/process. The process involves:

1. I point a void (improvement scope) to the client.
2. I look out for personnel in my company, if we could cater it.
3. I pitch to the client, if we could fill that void.

And we term this whole process as UPSELL.

**Note:** This personnel would mean more cost to the client. Its not necessarily free.

For reasons, it doesn't sound like adding value. It sounds like benefiting my company alone, not the client.

Is there any better word for the same, which means adding value to the client as well?

Comment: promote promote promote

Comment: I can't think of any single word, but lots of two- and three-word phrases could be coined. "Cooperative Service Enhancement", "Service Expansion", "Tailored Service Provision" etc

Comment: I love upsell !

Comment: Are you trying to find an alternative word **for your team to use, when talking amongst yourselves**, or **for you to use to the client** - ??

Comment: Joe, Infact both. But most importantly, with the client.

Comment: Upselling is what the pimple-faced teenager at McDonald’s does when he sulkily asks you if you want an extra sundae or salad or doughnut or something else with your menu (supersize, yes?). It means the right thing, but I agree it's not a good word to use with your clients if you want to sound like you're providing an extra service, rather than just raking in extra money from them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment above that *upsell* (as normally used in the United States, anyway) refers to either (1) adding extra-price items to a preliminary order so as to increase the final price of the transaction, or (2) trying to persuade the customer to upgrade from the product model that he or she originally selected to a more expensive model. Neither effort is motivated by a sincere concern for the best interests of the customer.

If what you do is identify a need that the customer isn't fully (or at all) aware of and then sell a specially formulated service to satisfy that need, you might consider a lengthier term for it, such as "customized service to match the client's needs." In any case, I would stay away from *upsell*, even if the term were accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't hike the price for the extra services, there is the recognised term 'value added'!

> Outside of economics, **value added** refers to "extra" feature(s) of
>   an item of interest (product, service, person etc.) that go beyond the
>   standard expectations and provide something "more" while adding little
>   or nothing to its cost.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_added)

Comment: Edwin, It would also include additional cost. What do you recommend then?

Comment: Go with the car etc industries: 'optional extras' / 'upgrades'.

Comment: Just BTW, "value added" is usually used to mean, the client/purchasor gets more even though having to pay a little more. (I edited the screw-up on the wikipedia page.)

Comment: I think' value added' is the content or possible result of   upsellig. OP is asking for another verb to replace 'upsell'. Probably 'promote' comes close to it.

Comment: I would never use "value added" when talking to a client; it's one step down from saying "here's a con to take more money from you" :)

Comment: OP also asked for 'which means adding value to the client as well' which licenses a noun.